# .NET Unit test runner for iOS

Tags: ios, unit-testing, mono, nunit, xamarin.ios

Has anyone written (or know about) a .net unit-test runner, preference to [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/), that runs **on** iOS ? or do I have to roll my own ?

My goal is to execute the unit tests on the simulator or devices. So far I've seen quite a few posts / blogs on mocking monotouch.dll (but running the tests on a PC) and one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877217/configuring-the-nunit-command-line-to-run-monotouch-tests) stating the lack of such tool.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As promised here's my own [solution](https://spouliot.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/unit-testing-and-monotouch/) for my problem :-) I hope it can help other people too!

**EDIT**

> Sounds like you'd have to write a MonoDevelop add-in that serves up an API for remote NUnit runners to send data to. Not really a trivial task.

The [original](https://spouliot.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/unit-testing-and-monotouch/) [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit) was updated to include support for [network logging](https://spouliot.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/touch-unit-network-logger/) (albeit not inside MonoDevelop).

**EDIT #2** : A similar runner [now exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046596/monodroid-which-testing-frameworks-work/7948017#7948017) for Mono for Android.

**FINAL EDIT**: Touch.Unit is now an integreal part of MonoTouch [releases](http://ios.xamarin.com/Releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.2) (starting with version 5.2) and does not have to be downloaded seperately.

Comment: That looks extreeemly awesome!

Comment: @JonasStawski Can't say, never tried. OTOH many NUnit-compatible libs exists so it's a matter of trying them. It would also make a good SO question IMO ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I've wanted the same thing myself for quite some time.  I think building one is the only option...

Can't imagine porting this GUI to iOS:

> [image]

I think the only reasonable solution might be to show a simple UITableView on the device/simulator with test name and red/green checkmarks, and post the full NUnit results via http to server software somewhere.

Sounds like you'd have to write a MonoDevelop add-in that serves up an API for remote NUnit runners to send data to.  Not really a trivial task.

Comment: That's pretty much what I had in mind (new runner + network reporting). I started looking at NUnitLite and got some MonoTouch.Dialog code for the UI over the weekend but then it hits me I could be duplicating someone else work (while saving me a lot of time). I still hoping... but will continue coding ;-)

Comment: I think the key feature would integrating into MonoDevelop including project template, etc.  Are you planning on starting an open source project for it?  iNUnit would be a good ludicrous name to use... maybe iUnit...

Comment: I'm an optimist so I'm still hoping to find an existing solution ;-) but if do anything (a bit) useful then it will be released as open source. OTOH it's a bit early to find names or plan MonoDevelop integration :-)