# Monotouch UITableView or MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: c#, iphone, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am building an iPhone app with MonoTouch and it gets its data from a web service.

The trouble I am having is that the first screen gets a list of say countries. When the user selects a country it should then retrieve the list of cities from the web service only for that selected country... Once a city is selected, the user is then taken through 2-3 more screens to add additional details like text, dates etc and there is a confirmation screen on the end where all the data is collected and posted to the web service.

I am struggling to find an optimum solution and determine if this can be achieved with MonoTouch.Dialog or if I should be using standard `UINavigation` views.

I have tried the first list with dialog and it successfully lists the countries that can be selected and they show an empty view when selected with a back button, however I am stuck in trying to find a way to populate that next view.

Any help please?

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several samples available for [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog), starting with it's own [Sample](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/Sample) application that will show you how to use every elements (and multiple levels).

Another one is [Touch.Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065071/net-unit-test-runner-for-ios/7591888#7591888) that [shows something similar](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit/blob/master/NUnitLite/TouchRunner/TouchRunner.cs#L255) to what you want to do, i.e. it initialize its UI from a list of `TestSuite` (instead of countries) and, when selected, shows a list of `TestCase` (instead of cities). That should be very close to what you're trying to achieve.